# Postgres: Set unique index on JSON field of array type

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-index, gist-index

There is a table like following:

```
CREATE TABLE test (my_field jsonb NOT NULL)
```

The `my_field` has a key like `collection` which stores values in `varchar[]` format:

```
{my_field: {collection: ['a', 'b', 'c']}}
```

I know that it is possible to set unique index for simple json values. For instance, for `{my_field: {name: 'Someone'}}`, uniqe constraint could be set. (gave it a try already)

I have tried `exclude using gist` a lot, but I've got nothing so far.

Is it possible to set unique(considering overlapping) constraint in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want a UK ofr array?.. ordered or not?.. ['a','b'] <> ['b','a']?..

Comment: It is not matter of ordering, uniqueness is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not matter of ordering then simple index will work:

```
so=# CREATE TABLE test (my_field jsonb NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
so=# insert into test select '{"my_field": {"collection": ["a", "b", "c"]}}';
INSERT 0 1
so=# create unique index uk_c on test ((my_field->'my_field'->>'collection'));
CREATE INDEX
so=# insert into test select '{"my_field": {"collection": ["a", "b", "c"]}}';
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_c"
DETAIL:  Key (((my_field -> 'my_field'::text) ->> 'collection'::text))=(["a", "b", "c"]) already exists.
```

Comment: What if I insert just ["a", "b"]?

Comment: I need something like overlapping (&&). I appreciate your concern man.